# How to set earlier Android SDK version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android. I got a project from someone else that has minSDKversion=16 and targetSdkVersion=23 in build.gradle

I installed android sdk 24 when I installed Android Studio. I expect I need to download Android SDK 23 and reference it in Android Studio but I haven't found out how to do that after much reading.

If I want to ensure that earlier Android release/Android APIs work don't I need to install the earlier SDKs ?

```
 Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'
```

Also I realize I could reference the version 23 sdk path in Android Studio but I can't find anywhere to download it from.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have the target sdk, do this to install your target sdk which is 23 in your case :

> Tools > Android > SDK Manager > Launch Standalone SDK Manager

Now click on **SDK Platform** under your target `API` version and install it.(as shown in the screenshot)

Done!

Here's a screenshot of the Standalone SDK Manager:

[image: Standalone SDK Manager]

**UPDATE**

Here's how to find SDK Manager :

[image]

Comment: When I go to https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html I just see 2009 releases and olde. Maybe someone has put a bad link in this page also to current Android SDK -- it just goes to an Android Studio download. Where would I find more recent Android SDK's to download.

Comment: I realize I could reference the version 23 sdk path in Android Studio but I can't find anywhere to download it from.

Comment: just follow the above steps to go to the Android SDK Manager, you can download it from there!

Comment: I don't have Android/SDK Manager under Tools (I have a Mac) ... searching

Comment: Strange. You must have a different version of Android Studio. I needed to close the project and then click Configure on a separate screen. (no link from tools) In any case I have it now thanks.

Comment: Oh but it was always in tools in my case, btw I've Android Studio 2.1.2, what's your version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117125/discussion-between-user1069528-and-ashish-ranjan).

Answer (score 1):

Install SDK 23 version or:
Update build.Gradle(Module:app) - Make sure is the one under Gradle Script and it is NOT build.Gradle(Project: yourproject)
 example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```